# Filter Collection of Objects to check if they have properties part of an array

Tags: c#, lambda

Given a string collection:

```
List<string> roles;
```

And a User Definition:

```
public class User
{
  public List<Role> Roles {get;set;}
}

public class Role {
  public string RoleName {get;set;}
}
```

If I had a List **users** and string collection **roles** how can I filter users who have the specified roles in the roles array?

```
List<string> roles = ...;
List<User> users = ...;
List<User> filteredUsers = new List<User>();

//I am stuck trying to figure out a single lambda expression to populate filteredUsers
filteredUsers = users.FindAll(u => u.Roles.Contains(r => r.RoleName.Contains(roles)));
```

So if roles contained "Admin, SuperUser" filteredUsers would just be Admins and Super Users.

Comment: What do you mean by "single lambda expression"? Do you not like nesting lambda expressions?

Comment: Your body says "filter _out_" but then you want to find those that match.

Comment: by now we should actually have a canonical duplicate for this kind of question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var filteredUsers = users.Where(x => x.Roles.Any(z => roles.Contains(z.RoleName)));
```

Note: if you are using LINQ to db (e.g. Entity Framework) the performance will be abysmal.

Comment: I wouldn't expect performance to necessarily be abysmal - I'm pretty sure at least *some* out-of-process LINQ queries like this would be optimized to basically send `roles` up as a query parameter, and perform a join using that. It's worth checking, for sure... but I wouldn't *assume* it'll be bad.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
private List<string> Allow { get; set; }
Func<User,bool> filter => (user) => 
   Allow.Any(a => user.Roles.Any(r => r==a)));
```

Now when you need to filter the users just use `filter` as the parameter for you Linq predicate.

Usage:

```cs
    Allow = roles;
    filteredUsers = users.Where(filter).ToList();
```